# How do i re run a program based on answer from the user on python (yes or no)?

Tags: python, ocr

```
UserSen = input("Please type in a sentence without punctuation: ") #This will allow the user to input a sentence
UserSen = UserSen.lower()  #This will covert the whole sentence to lower case
UserSen = str.split(UserSen)   #This will return all the words in the UserSen as a list using str. as a separator

Word_To_Find = input("Please enter a word you want to search for in the sentence: ")  #This will allow the user to input a word to find
Word_To_Find = Word_To_Find.lower()  #This will covert the word to be searched into lower case

Position = []  #Variable position is declared so it can be used later in the search part (for loop)
Sentence_length = (len(UserSen))  #Measure length of sentence

if Word_To_Find not in UserSen: #If the word to search is not in sentence
    print ("Error this word: ",Word_To_Find,"isn`t in the sentence" )#Display error message if word is not in the sentence
else: # But if the word is found starts another iteration
    for i in range(0,Sentence_length): # Range will generate sequences of numbers in the form of a list and select the position withing the sentence and store it in the (i)ndex.
        if UserSen[i] == Word_To_Find: #if the index is equivalent to the word
            Position.append(i+1) # this will fill the empty variable i declared earlier with position(s) as this will add the word to the position list
print ("Search successful. The word",Word_To_Find,"' has been found in position:",Position) # This will display the position of the word if the word is found
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Each line of code should start with 4 spaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way in python to repeat a while or for loop by asking the user to do so at the end of the loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113728/is-there-any-way-in-python-to-repeat-a-while-or-for-loop-by-asking-the-user-to-d)

Comment: `positions = [pos for pos, s in enumerate(UserSen, start=1) if s == Word_To_Find]`

Comment: The useless comments make this much hard to read.  Please study https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments

Comment: sorry i posted my code below, how can i re run de program if the word is not in the sentence based on the input of the user?

Answer (score 0):

```
run_again = 'yes'

while run_again == 'yes':
    # your original program here

    run_again = ''
    while run_again not in ('yes', 'no'):
        run_again = input('run again (yes/no)?')
```